# How to animate through an array of CGPoints in Sprite Kit - Swift

Tags: ios, swift3, sprite-kit

How can I animate a `SKSpriteNode` from a array of `CGPoints` in swift? I would also like the `SKSpriteNode` to rotate towards the next position it is going to. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per @KnightOfDragon's suggestion, you can make a path and make the node to follow it, like this:

```
class GameScene: SKScene {


    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {


        //1. create points
        let points = [
            CGPoint(x:frame.minX,y:frame.minY),
            CGPoint(x:frame.maxX,y:frame.maxY),
            CGPoint(x:frame.maxX,y:frame.midY),
            CGPoint.zero
                      ]

        //2. Create a path
        let path = CGMutablePath()

        //3. Define starting point
        path.move(to: points[0])

        //4. Add additional points
        for point in points[1..<points.count]{

            print("point : \(point)")
            path.addLine(to: point)
        }

        //5. Create an action which will make the node to follow the path
        let action = SKAction.follow(path, speed: 122)

        let sprite = SKSpriteNode(color: .white, size: CGSize(width: 100, height: 100))

        addChild(sprite)

        sprite.run(action, withKey: "aKey")

    }
}
```

This might be more convenient than accepted answer in the case that you want the node to orient to the path that it follows (`zRotation` property animates so that the node turns to follow the path).

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene,SKSceneDelegate {


    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

        //1. create points
        let points = [CGPoint(x:120,y:20),CGPoint(x:220,y:20),CGPoint(x:40,y:320)]

        var actions = [SKAction]()

        //2. Create actions
        for point in points {
            actions.append(SKAction.move(to: point, duration: 1))
        }

        let sprite = SKSpriteNode(color: .white, size: CGSize(width: 100, height: 100))

        addChild(sprite)

        //3. Create the action sequence from previously created actions
        let sequence = SKAction.sequence(actions)

        //4. Run the sequence (use the key to stop this sequence)
        sprite.run(sequence, withKey:"aKey")

    } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, is there any way to rotate the SKSpriteNode towards the direction it is moving to?

Comment: Also, can I make the speed a constant for each animation?

Comment: Look at the Aiming part of this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36235426/3402095). To solve constant speed, use formula Time = Distance / Speed. If you get stuck, ask another question and me or somebody else will answer it, because this is different topic and you already have an answer to your original question...

Comment: surprised you took this approach instead of making a CGPath

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Well, I guess I just have put the same amount of effort in answer as OP did in his question :) I don't know, this is the first thing that came to my mind and I wrote an answer in 30 seconds :) But yeah, maybe your way is more suitable for OP. Also it seems more memory wise, but without testing, who knows ;) (I mean I don't know what `CGMutablePath` does behind the scenes).